# Reversing a singly-linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, reverse, singly-linked-list

On a job interview I was asked to reverse a single linked list. Here is what my solution was:

```
public class E<T>{
    private E<T> next;
    private T val;

    private E(T val) {
        this.val = val;
    }

    public static <T> E<T> createNode(T val){
        return new E<T>(val);
    }

    public E<T> add(E<T> next){
        E<T> current = this;
        while(current.next != null){
            current = current.next;
        }
        current.next = next;
        return this;
    }

    public E<T> reverse(){
        if(this.next == null)
            return this;
        E<T> previous = new E<>(this.val); //<----- HERE
        E<T> current = this.next;
        while(current != null){ 
            E<T> tmp = current.next;
            this.val = current.val;
            this.next = previous;
            current.next = previous;
            previous = current;
            current = tmp;
        }
        return this;
    }
}
```

But it does look ugly. The issue I could not understand how to deal with was that we initially had only `this` reference which we could not assign to anything (we just ended up with a cycle then). That was the reason I created a new node. But it looks as a terrible workaround. Is there a "true way" to do that?

Comment: You are aware of `Collections.reverse(List<?> list)`, right?

Comment: I think hes supposed to actually know the algorithm in an interview.

Comment: @Mena The question was pure alogorithmic, but yes I supposed that something like that was in JDK already.

Comment: @Alupkers the thing is, even if you were tested on the actual algorithm rather than your knowledge of Java, you can take a look at the source for `Collections.reverse`. Collections-related stuff in Java is supposedly highly optimized, so you can stare at some pretty decent source code and figure it out from there (from the javadoc: "This method runs in linear time").

Comment: @Mena Yes, I just looked at it. It uses __two__ iterators (start-end and end-start) which does not quite satisfy my requirements.

Comment: @Alupkers ah yes, I just read between the lines now.

Answer (score 1):

If you some reason you can not use collection utility function like Collections.reverse like Mena told you can implement roughly as :

```
public Iterable<T> Reverse<T>(Iterable<T> queue)
{
    Stack<T> stack = new Stack<T>();  
    while(!queue.isEmpty())
       stack.push(queue.pop());

    return stack;
}
```

(*this is pseudo code not real implementation)

#### Edit: inplace version

```
public void Reverse<T>(Iterable<T> queue)
{   
    //todo: add null check
    Stack<T> stack = new Stack<T>();  
    while(!queue.isEmpty())
       stack.push(queue.pop());

    while(!stack.isEmpty())
       queue.append(stack.pop());
}
```

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted. We have to __mutate__ the original list. This is where problems come...

Answer (score 1):

Well, one way of doing that is using recursion:

```
public E<T> reverse() {
    if (this.next == null) return this;
    E<T> node = this.next.reverse();
    this.next.next = this;
    this.next = null;
    return node;
}
```

I did test it, this works smoothly, however you may end up into trouble if the list is too long: call stack may explode.

The iterative way:

```
public E<T> reverse() {
    E<T> previous = null;
    E<T> current = this;
    E<T> next = this.next;
    while (next != null) {
        current.next = previous;
        previous = current;
        current = next;
        next = current.next;
    }
    current.next = previous; // We haven't reversed the last node yet.
    return current;
}
```

Again, this has been tested, and produces the desired effect.

Also, the `add` method can be improved so that it takes constant time:

```
public E<T> add(E<T> node) {
    node.next = this;
    return node;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, no, it won't. It contains the same mistake that I made... You're assigning `this`. It introduces a cycle of references. We cannot assign `this`, only `this.next`.

Comment: @Alupkers There was a problem with my code, however it had nothing to do with a cycle of references. I corrected it `node.next = this` --> `this.next.next = this`

Comment: It depends on the order of operations. If you do it the right way, there is no problem. In my code, I assign this after the subsequent elements to this have been reversed. You are welcome to add some printing to my code to understand how the operations are performed.

Answer (score 1):

you will have access to HEAD node. So, You can start with HEAD node and just change the direction of the links till the end. At last, make your HEAD->next as null and the last node as HEAD.

Something like. ( I haven't tested it.. just writing the idea in some pseudo code)

```
cur = head.next;
prev = head;

while(cur)
{
    next = cur.next;
    cur.next = prev;
    prev = cur;
    cur = next;
} 

head.next = null;
head = cur;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a recursive piece of code that solves the problem:

```
public E<T> reverse() {
    if(next == null) return this;
    else {
        E<T> r = next.reverse();
        this.next = null;
        r.add(this);
        return r;
    }
}
```

And here the piece of code that solves the problem in an iterative way:

```
public E<T> reverse() {
    E<T> n = this;
    E<T> last = null;

    while(n.next != null) {
        E<T> temp = n.next;
        n.next = last;
        last = n;
        n = temp;
    }

    n.next = last;

    return n;
}
```